# c++ threading 'no matching overloaded function found'

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

```
#include <thread>

void f(int*& ptr)
{
    ptr = new int[4];
    ptr[0] = 0;
    ptr[1] = 1;
    ptr[2] = 2;
    ptr[3] = 3;
}

int main()
{
    int* ptr;

    std::thread thread{ f, ptr };
    thread.join();

    delete[] ptr;
    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand what I'm missing. I tried different combinations of reference or non-reference, checked whether I have the same format as in the documentation. Nothing. I still get this error:

```
Error C2672: 'std::invoke': no matching overloaded function found
```

Comment: Please post error messages as *text*. *Never* as images. Thanks.

Comment: You have to use at least  `std::ref(ptr)`  otherwise it'll be passed by value (but it might be failing on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your function `f` takes a reference to a pointer. However, threads can't store reference-arguments for later invocation, so you must use a pointer to a pointer instead.

```cpp
#include <thread>

void f(int** ptr)
{
    *ptr = new int[4];
    *ptr[0] = 0;
    *ptr[1] = 1;
    *ptr[2] = 2;
    *ptr[3] = 3;
}

int main()
{
    int* ptr;

    std::thread thread{f, &ptr};
    thread.join();

    delete[] ptr;
    return 0;
}
```

**Note:** You can initialize the array in a much prettier way using:

```cpp
*ptr = new int[] {0, 1, 2, 3};
```

Comment: Do note, you can use `std::ref` to "pass a reference" to a thread